# Problemas para leer palabras de un fichero y guardarlas en un arreglo en C

Tags: c

Quiero leer palabras en un fichero y guardarlas en un array diccionario, pero se me dificulta. Creo que el problema es que estoy usando `fscanf` aunque me den el archivo como argumento.

Este código tiene que preguntar la longitud del diccionario que queremos y lanzar un error si el tamaño es distinto a la cantidad de palabras del archivo. Luego leer el archivo que se pasa como parámetro y ponerlo en el array char ** biblioteca y preguntar por la clave. Con lo primero y lo último no tengo problemas.

```
int cargar_diccionario(FILE *fich_dicc) 
{
  int longitud;
  int i;
  if(fich_dicc == NULL)
  {
    return NOLEE;
    printf("%d", NOLEE);
  }
  else
  { 
    printf("Introducir longitud del alfabeto: ");
    int result = scanf("%d", &n_palabras);
    fseek(fich_dicc, 0, SEEK_SET);
    longitud = contarPalabras(fich_dicc);
    if(n_palabras != longitud)
    {
      printf("%d\n", NOPAL);
      return NOPAL;
    }
    else
    {
      diccionario = (char **)malloc(n_palabras * sizeof(char *));
      printf("Direccion de memoria de diccionario antes de asignacion: %p\n", (void *)diccionario);
      if(diccionario == NULL)
      {
          printf("%d",NOMEM);
          return NOMEM;
      }
      else{
        char *palabra;
        for (i = 0; i < n_palabras; i++) 
        {
          diccionario[i] = (char *)malloc(100);
          if (diccionario[i] == NULL) {
              // Manejar error de asignación de memoria
              printf("Error al asignar memoria para la palabra %d del diccionario.\n", i);
              return NOMEM;
          }
          if (fscanf(fich_dicc, "%s", diccionario[i]) != 1) {
              printf("Error al leer la palabra %d del diccionario.\n", i);
              return NOLEE;
          }
          printf("Palabra %d: %s\n", i, diccionario[i]);
        }
        fclose(f);
        printf("Introducir clave cesar: ");
        result = scanf("%d", &clave_cesar);
        int rango = -25;
        if(clave_cesar> n_palabras|| clave_cesar<1 || clave_cesar>25 || result != 1)/*mirar lo del -25*/
        {
          printf("%d", NOCLA);
          return NOCLA; 
        }
      }
    } 
  }
  printf("%d\n", n_palabras);
  return n_palabras;
}
```